# Print out the rest of sentence after the first occurrence of the letter in the sentence

Tags: java, input

How do I print the rest of the sentence after the first occurrence of the letter in the sentence?

I tried, however, it prints only the sentence and letter I give in the console.

> Example: Sentence - How are you?
> Letter - a
> O/P: re you?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
      String sentence = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
      String letter = sc.next();

      System.out.println(sentence);
      System.out.println(letter);

      // int dec = -1;
      // String str = String.valueOf(dec);

      if (sentence.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
         System.out.println("The letter does not exist in the sentence.");
      } else {
         letter = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(letter) + 1);
      }

      sc.close();
   }
}
```

Enter a sentence: hello world
Enter a letter: w
hello world
w
The letter does not exist in the sentence.

It not works, it shows given letter does not exist, but in the sentence "w" the letter is present.

Comment: you forgot to ask a question. Please [edit] the post and ask a focused question.

Comment: Your code actually works correctly, the variable `letter` contains the answer, just add a System.out.println(letter); in your `else` condition.

Comment: I added but it shows, the letter does not exist in the sentence. I need to show the rest of the sentence after the letter which I have given in input. For example: Enter Sentence: Hello world!   Enter Letter: w  Output: orld!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String` variable `letter` is set to the letter you want to find, but then you overwrite it with the resulting sentence. After that, you do nothing with the variable.

You should instead save the result to a different variable, such as `sentencePart`, then print out that variable. Otherwise your code is confusing to read.

```
if (sentence.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
    System.out.println("The letter does not exist in the sentence.");
} else {
    String sentencePart = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(letter) + 1);
    System.out.println("The sentence part is " + sentencePart);
}
```